# How to fix a Ghostscript OS Error when using Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ghostscript

This is the error I am getting:

```
OS Error: Ghostscript not found on paths
```

When running the following function:

```
from PIL import Image
def convert_ps_to_png(ps_file):
    img = Image.open(ps_file)  
    img = Image.save("file.png")# Error occurs on this line

convert_ps_to_png(ps_file_path)
```

Any solutions would be appreciated. The end goal is to convert a .ps file to a .png file through a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answers to your previous questions, you need to have Ghostscript installed, and available in the system environment variable $PATH.